# IRC channel of Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, irc

Is there any [IRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) channel for Stack Exchange?

Reason for asking the question:

I was trying to figure out best out of two books which have very less information on Internet in forms of review, etc. So I thought I should ask it on a Stack Exchange site. But I came to know that Stack Exchange doesn't encourage recommendation type questions. That's where the thought of IRC channel came to my mind. I am open to suggestions and any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Stack Exchange doesn't have its own IRC channel. It has its own chat, where you can participate if you have 20 or more points on any site - even the ones where you don't have an account.

Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange are the exception to this, for them you need 20 points on the site itself. But the association bonus counts for this. If you have 200 points on any Stack Exchange site, you get 100 points on every associated Stack Exchange account. This is called the "association bonus". These 100 points are sufficient for using chat on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange, too.

Chat rooms have their own rules, defined by their respective room owners and regulars; not every chatroom will be open to your question. Find one where your type of question is allowed.

There is an important difference between Stack Exchange chatrooms and IRC channels: Stack Exchange chatrooms are visible to the public. Not everybody can chat, but the *entire world* can read. This is something to keep in mind when using Stack Exchange chat.

Comment: If I don't have 20 reputations??

Comment: @Tetragrammaton I see you have 38 points on Ask Ubuntu, so you could look for a chatroom there. Chatrooms are less restrictive than the rest of SE. They don't have to stay on-topic, unless the rules of the room explicitly say so. You could even ask in the room itself if your question is allowed there; if you're being polite about it (and take a possible "no" gracefully), you should be OK.

Comment: ok, very instructive answer and suggestions.

Comment: @Tetragrammaton then you should accept it.

Comment: @Tetragrammaton If you have 20 rep on *any* site (except SO or Meta.SE), then you can participate in the chatrooms for any site (except for SO and Meta.SE), including the ones which you don't have 20 rep on. (cc S.L.Barth, you may want to update your answer)

Comment: @angussidney You're right. Just tried to join a chatroom on a site where I don't have an account, and even that, I could do. Updated my answer. Thanks!